# ECMASCRIPT6 Google Tag Manager Error: Arrow function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a compile error in Google TAG Manager (GTM) with below script:

**This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.**

Tried to google it but my understanding of JS doesn't seem to be enough. Any ideas on how to change it so Google TAG Manager can compile it?

```
var modellist = productList.Lockers.reduce((acc, item) => {
    var existItem = acc.find(({
        model
    }) => model === item.model);
    var existItemnew = acc.find(({
        modelname
    }) => modelname === item.modelname);
    if (!existItem) {
        acc.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: whatever TAG manager is ... does it have a `ECMASCRIPT6 mode`?

Comment: "Any ideas on why?" — Because it is a true fact. [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) were introduced in ES6 and are syntax errors in older versions of the JavaScript language.

Comment: according to https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript arrow functions are available in sandboxed templates or some such

Comment: Updated the question to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your arrow functions into traditional functions. Your code would then look something like this:

```
var modellist = productList.Lockers.reduce(
  function(acc, item){
    var existItem = acc.find(
      function({ model }){
        return model === item.model;
      }
    );
    var existItemnew = acc.find(
      function({ modelname }){
        return modelname === item.modelname;
      }
    );
    if (!existItem) { acc.push(item); }
    return acc;
  }, []
);

$.each(modellist, function(i, item) {
  var model = modellist[i].model;
  var modelname = modellist[i].modelname;
  $('.filter.first .dropdown').append('<div class="' + model + '"><input type="radio" name="model" id="' + model + '" value="' + model + '" /><label>' + modelname + '</label>(<span id="modelcount"></span>)<img></div>');

});
```

There are a few important differences between these two types of functions in JavaScript. To learn about these, check out some online resources like [Arrow Functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: The clamps inside ({ modelname }) is giving me an error: 'destructuring binding' is available in ES6 and wont compile. If I remove the clamps the error is gone but my function doesnt work corretcly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Change the arrow functions like `(acc, item) => { ... }` to non-arrow functions like `function (acc, item) { ... }`.

Object destructuring is also not allowed here, so `function ({model}) { ... }` needs to become `function(i) { var model = i.model; ... }`.
The following is the fixed version.

```js
var modellist = productList.Lockers.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    var existItem = acc.find(function (i) {
        return i.model === item.model
    });
    var existItemnew = acc.find(function (i) {
        return i.modelname === item.modelname
    });
    if (!existItem) {
        acc.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

$.each(modellist, function (i, item) {

    var model = modellist[i].model;
    var modelname = modellist[i].modelname;
    $('.filter.first .dropdown').append('<div class="' + model + '"><input type="radio" name="model" id="' + model + '" value="' + model + '" /><label>' + modelname + '</label>(<span id="modelcount"></span>)<img></div>');

});
```

Comment: the clamps inside ({model}) gives me an compile error in Tag manager:  'destructuring binding' is available in ES6. If I remove them the Each function doesnt work and creates one element for each json obect this is targeting. any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. Instead of destructuring the argument as in ES6, `model` and `modelname` properties can be accessed using the usual dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are right, the error message says exactly what's wrong: some clients don't support ES6, and yours seems to be one of them. I've written an example of how you'll have to replace it:

```
var existItem = acc.find(function(model) { model === item.model});
```

These two functions are (mainly) the same:

```
let myArrowFunction = (text) => console.log(text) // es6, not completely supported (newer)

let myStandardFunction = function(text) { // standard JavaScript, accepted everywhere (original)
  console.log(text)
}
```

And you'll have to use the second version.